# Does the probability of false positives with BIP157-8 depend on the number of TXs in the block?

Tags: compact-client-side-block-filters

If a block has much fewer transactions than average, let’s say 63 like 4MB block `774628`, will keys have less probability to falsely match against its BIP157-8 compact filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, BIP158 basic filters have a fixed false positive rate of exactly 1/784931, regardless of how many elements they contain.

Answer (score 1):

Just ftr. The 1/784931 fpr is for bitcoin core and compatible. Wasabi filter's parameters are different because Wasabi wallets are expected to have more keys than average bitcoin core wallets given coinjoins and remixes.

Comment: Wasabi doesn't use BIP158 filters.

Comment: @PieterWuille Wasabi does use BIP158 filters AFAIU.
https://docs.wasabiwallet.io/FAQ/FAQ-UseWasabi.html#what-are-bip-158-block-filters
https://docs.wasabiwallet.io/using-wasabi/BIPs.html

Comment: Well BIP158 specifies the parameters for the filter, including the 1/784931 false positive rate. It's possible it uses a (very) similar design, but IIRC at least the filter contents is different, and the parameters are different.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this.